# Facebook javascript payment dialog loads then disappears without calling the callback function

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I managed to get a button to work to call the facebook pay dialog and all was dandy, it opened with the correct data and called the purchase callback page at the correct times with the correct data.

Now though it is not displaying after loading (though I don't think any of the data (or even the code) has changed).

When I click the button the payment dialog opens up saying loading, and all of the database changes done by the purchase callback page that are done when the dialog opens are done properly and completely. Next the loading dialog disappears and my javascript callback function is not called and nothing else happens at all.

If I change the data so that, for example, the price is a string rather than a number then I get the payment dialog open up with the correct error instead of just the loading screen and my callback function is called.

I am not sure what the problem is, here is my code for calling the payment UI:

```
FB.ui({  
    method: 'pay',  
    order_info: {  
        pkgnum: d.id,  
        title: d.name,  
        description: d.desc,  
        price: d.cost,  
        image_url: 'images/coin.png',  
        product_url: 'images/coin.png',  
        userid: username  
    },  
    purchase_type: 'item'  
}, fbPurchaseCallback );
```

And here is the data the UI receives for displaying the item payment information:

```
{
    "content":[{
        "pkgnum":20,
        "title":"Lolname",
        "description":"Loldesc",
        "price":100,
        "image_url":"images/coin.png",
        "product_url":"images/coin.png",
        "userid":"254884",
        "item_id":"254884"
    }],
    "method":"payments_get_items"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with facebook being unable to find `images/coin.png` for some reason. Solved now.